# Getting empty result on extracting data from Javascript website using scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to extract data from a website that give the information like this:

```
<html>
<head>
......
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
      'author': 'author name',
      'editor': 'editor name',
      'article_id': '954301',
      'article_title': " Article Title ",
      'pagination': 'page 1',
      'total_page': '1',
      'publish_date': '20210803',
      'publish_year': '2021',
      'publish_month': '08',
      'publish_day': '03',
      'publish_time': '20:04',
      'channel': 'finance',
      'sub-channel': 'macro',
      'regional': '',
      'type' : 'article',
      'content_type' : 'article',
      'topics' : 'topic1, topic2, topic3',
      'page_type' : 'article_page',
      'tags' : 'tag1,tag2,tag3',
      'user_id' : '',
      'register_date' : '',
      'data_source' : 'Non AMP'
    });
</script>
```

I used the following command:

```
data_content = response.xpath('//script[contains(text(),"author")]/text()').re(r'"author":"(\d+)"')
data = json.loads(data_content)   
author = data["author"]
```

And it's give an empty result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data_content = response.xpath('//script[contains(text(),"author")]/text()').get()
data_content = re.search(r'window.dataLayer.push\(({.+})\);', data, re.DOTALL)
data_content = data_content.group(1)
data_content = data_content.replace("'", '"')

data = json.loads(data_content)
author = data['author']

print(author)
author name
```